# A specific scheduling algorithm

Tags: algorithm, scheduling

The question I have concerns a hobby project that I'm working on to help out my wife with her work.

I realize that the problem I'm facing is quite similar to what's been answered on SO in numerous threads. However, I can't seem to find any thread that would address one little specific difference that I need to count in.

Here's a detailed description of the problem:

A teacher has numerous students that she teaches. Each student needs to have two lessons every week at least two days apart (i.e. Monday + Wednesday, Tuesday + Thursday etc.). The lessons are individual meaning there's only one student and the teacher in a class at a time. The teacher needs to have exactly one lunch break every day. The lunch break can be any time between two classes - the only condition is: a day cannot start or end in a lunch break. Each student provides their availability during a week (a list of possible time slots they can attend the class).

So far, this looks like a "regular" scheduling problem that there's bunch of material available online on.

But here's the catch: students are in different age meaning their lesson takes either 30 or 45 minutes. Younger students' lesson takes 30 minutes and olders' - 45 minutes. The goal of the algorithm is to find the optimal weekly schedule for the teacher. By optimal I mean a schedule where the teacher needs to spend least amount of time in school - all lessons back to back with no need for the teacher to wait for another student.

My first attempt was to come with all possible permutations of students' classes, lunch breaks and week days but for a 3 student schedule I came up with 13! permutations (that's roughly around 6 bln permutations). Here's why 13:

3 students - 2 classes each

4 lunch breaks (a 4 day week to keep the numbers small)

3 day breaks (a "night" so to speak)

The above gave me 13 elements to try in different permutations. However, after calculating the factorial I gave that up - 6 bln permutations will not be tried in any reasonable time on a "regular" machine. And that's just counting 3 students, the real-life data will be closer to 9 or 10. Obviously, the nonsense permutations (2 "nights" in a row, 2 classes for the same student on the same day and so on) would be thrown right away but still...

That was when I realized I'm not going to do this inventing the wheel by myself.

I did some research and came across Hopcroft-Karp algorithm. However I don't think it can be applied in a mixed timespan slots scenario (30/45 minute lessons). Am I wrong? Then I found some info on genetic algorithms. However, again I am not sure if they can take the mixed timespan condition into account?

I would greatly appreciate any pointers as to which directions my research should go.

Comment: "all lessons back to back with no need for the teacher to wait for another student": this makes the solution very unlikely and computationally expensive (few successful schedules) because there are no restrictions on the time periods the students can offer (ie their availability). For example, student 1's availability is Mon, Wed 8:30, student 2's is 8:31 then the constraint system will not be satisfiable. You either need to make sure there are 'enough' offers from each student, or at least restrict starting times so the search space is smaller.

Comment: What are the working hours? How long should the lunch break be? (e.g. 8:30 - 17:00 with 30' break, monday to friday) What are the earliest and latest acceptable times for the lunch break?